# PHP commands the same when adding to an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Just curious if doing this

```
$this->item['foo'] = $this->action(3);
$this->item['bar'] = $this->action(1);
$this->item['baz'] = $this->action(1);
```

is the same as doing

```
$this->item = ($this->item +
[
    'foo'  => $this->action(3),
    'bar'  => $this->action(1),
    'baz'  => $this->action(1),
]);
```

if you could explain why/why not I'd be appreciative

Comment: Yes its valid PHP 5.4+ for handling arrays.... @ whoever downvoted and left a nasty remark.... then quickly retracted and deleted, lol

Comment: New in 5.4: [short syntax for arrays](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays)

Comment: @bishop +1 for you knowing this too ;)

Comment: Learned something new today

Comment: @KA_lin just keep in mind that this only works for PHP version 5.4 and up ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're not equivalent if `$this->item` already has any of the keys you're specifying. From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

> for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

You can resolve this by switching the order of arguments:

```
$this->item = (
    [
    'foo'  => $this->action(3),
    'bar'  => $this->action(1),
    'baz'  => $this->action(1),
    ] + $this->item);
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I though that there would be an issue with the ordering but wasn't certain. Thanks again for confirming it, plus 1 and waiting to accept.